# XMLWriter vs SimpleXML. Which one is faster?

Tags: php, performance, simplexml, xmlwriter

I basicly need to load the whole XML file, add a new line with content and then saving it. But I wondered which one is faster.. XMLWriter or SimpleXML? Oh, and, it's mainly large XML files, more then 10MB.

Thanks!

Comment: Write a test harness and measure it.

Comment: Are you going to repeatedly append elements/data to the same xml document at the (more or less) same location?

Comment: Depends on the user.. It's a system that can add links and directories. Each user has its own xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [PHP's manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlwriter.php), XMLWriter *"provides a non-cached, forward-only means of generating streams or files containing XML data."*

It cannot be used to load a document and modify it, therefore it's not an option and you're pretty much left with SimpleXML.

Comment: Thanks for the tech translation!

Comment: You could combine an XMLReader and XMLWriter. But I doubt it to be faster in php.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but while researching the advantages of each approach, I stumbled over this performance test: https://p0l0.binware.org/2011/07/04/simplexml-vs-xmlwriter-vs-dom/

A summary:
XMLWriter is the fastest of the three approaches, while using dismissably more memory than SimpleXML.

A small file -circa 2mb- does not show a big difference between XMLWriter and SimpleXML. The bigger the XML file gets the bigger the speed difference between the two, with XMLWriter being clearly faster.

DOM is the resource heaviest and slowest and should not be used at all.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31193113)

Comment: @tomerpacific Wrote an extended summary which lines out the results of the performance test.